# When two different companies of hard disks can be raid together?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid1

I'm trying to replace the hard disk due to the aging of the server computer. Currently, the server computer is composed of two 2tb hard disks as RAID 1. The model number of the hard disk is Seagate's st2000dm001. Will the rebuild work correctly when you rebuild with "Western Digital WD 2TB Red WD20EFRX" after removing one of the existing hard disks?

And may I use the built-in program as rebuild?
The OS is Windows Server 2008 r2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a dead hard drive in RAID 5 with a different type](https://serverfault.com/questions/240170/replacing-a-dead-hard-drive-in-raid-5-with-a-different-type)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dead end of life operating system and hardware platform.

Comment: OS is irreverent in the OP’s question context.

Comment: @GregAskew - the relative support status of an OS is not a reason to *close* a question, in most cases

Answer (score 3):

As long as capacity of your new drive is => your old drive, you’ll be fine. You’ll get slowest drive write performance as a result, obviously, but this is minor drawback.